# How to configure RDS PostgresSQL DB inside AWS Lambda within VPC?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-rds

How can I move the DB Configuration and schema creation from Terraform into AWS Lambda, and then create a cloudwatch event which can invoke the Lambda to perform the operation.

This operation can be creating the connection, schema and then running some alembic scripts.

For example:

```
    provider "postgresql" {
  host     = "127.0.0.1"
  database = "${var.db1_name}"
  username = "my_role"
  password = "foobar"
  sslmode  = "disable"
}

resource "postgresql_schema" "my_schema1" {
  name = "my_schema"
}
```

If my schema.tf file looks like this,

How can these moved to lambda.py and package them together as a zip?
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Basically you are asking for an entire Lambda Function Code

Comment: Not entire code :) !!

Answer (score 1):

**Create RDS Instance using boto3**

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')

response = conn.create_db_instance(
        AllocatedStorage=10,
        DBName="test",
        DBInstanceIdentifier="my-first-rds-instance",
        DBInstanceClass="db.t2.micro",
        Engine="mysql",
        MasterUsername="root",
        MasterUserPassword="pass1234",
        Port=3306,
        VpcSecurityGroupIds=["sg-7fa4d512"],
    )

print (response)
```

If you want to configure other parameters for RDS you can have a look [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.create_db_instance).

**Create CloudWatch Event:**

```
import boto3

AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"

client = boto3.client('events', region_name=AWS_REGION)

response = cloudwatch.put_rule(
    Name='AlarmStateChange',
    EventPattern='{"source": ["aws.cloudwatch"], "detail-type": ["CloudWatch Alarm State Change"]}',
    State='ENABLED'
)

response = cloudwatch.put_targets(
    Rule='AlarmStateChange',
    Targets=[
        {
            'Arn': 'arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:585584209241:function:DemoFunction',
            'Id': 'myCloudWatchEventsTarget',
        }
    ]
)

print(response)
```

If you want to configure other parameters for CW you can have a look [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/events.html).

For Operation, you will have to create another Lambda Function and add the necessary code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Turns out, I figured this and it's helpful. But I was wondering about the automation of migration scripts adjacent to the lambda. Currently I use alembic upgrade and has a script for it. Is there an easy way to keep it adjacent to the lambda. Means once I create the connection, I could run the migration scripts from my AWS Lambda. Any pointer is helpful too. Thank you @Shivkumar Mallesappa

Comment: You can send a notification to SNS or send a message to  SQS, and upon that event, you can trigger multiple Lambdas. Hope this helps